# Netbeans stopped going to declaration (does not recognize element) and not does not highlight syntax

Tags: c++, netbeans, ide, virtual-machine

I am using Netbeans 8.0 (for c++) on Ubuntu 14.4 on a VirtualBox running on Windows 7.0.
Everything worked fine, syntax highlighting + autocomplete + go to declaration.

Right now autocomplete and go to declaration does not work and I am getting a message:

> Limited code assistance (no associated project)

Comment: You might take a look into the `~/.netbeans/8.0/var/log/messages.log` file. The NetBeans complains about some problems there

Comment: @HEKTO That file is about 0.6MB and has a lot of contents. I am not sure where to look for the issue.

Comment: Did you by any chance resolve it? I'm facing the same issue for the last couple of months, and the only thing I can do is add the files manually to parse.

Comment: @kliteyn Hi there. Good luck on your journey for a solution. If you do find one it would be an epic victory. i.e. no I haven't unless you consider using vim a solution which some arguably would. ;)

Comment: @zehelvion No solution other than adding each file to parse (right click->properties->...->add to parse)